# User Consent to read Outlook/Teams/Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have to read User emails (particular subfolder), One Drive, Team Channels and Sharepoint after some regular intervals at the background using Microsoft Graph API but not without having the user consent which should be taken only once when they logged in to the web based application first time and not afterwards. I am not sure where to start from and how this can be achieved? Should the token be stored forever in some database securely OR Is it the AAD?

Would really appreciate any pointers/APIs/Libraries/concepts or links which can help in moving towards this direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the token without user, [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) can be used. The flow permits a web service (confidential client) to use its own credentials, instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service.

In the client credentials flow, permissions are granted directly to the application itself by an administrator. So it is necessary to use the [**application permissions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions). You could call Microsoft Graph API with the access token.

For example, call this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get message:

You need to add one of the application permissions to API permission(navigate to Azure Active Directory-> your application), and click *grant for your tenant*.

[image]

Comment: I proposed the client credentials flow initially where backend service/application had all elevated access to read the mails of all users of the organization. However, this was rejected by the security/infra team adding a point that without the user's knowledge, the application should not be allowed to read user's emails which is the main requirement to rule out any legal privacy issue later. I have seen many mobile applications where the user consent is only taken once like to view photos or contacts of the user only once and not afterwards.

Comment: I wanted to understand, Is the same thing possible to achieve in Microsoft?